# WMI Filter to detect Windows 10 Creators Update or higher

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10, wmi

I have a group policy that needs to apply to Windows 10 Creators / version 1703 / Build 15063 and higher, (Specifically [Cross Domain Drive mappings](https://serverfault.com/questions/849777/creators-update-stops-cross-domain-gpo-drive-mapping-working-0x80090005-bad-da/874828#874828))

Until Fall Creators came out, detecting *specifically* for creators update worked with this code:

```
select * from Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like "10.0.15063%" AND ProductType="1"
```

But going forward, I need this to apply to both Creators and Fall Creators, and presumably, Redstone 4+

Because [BuildNumber is a String and not Integer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3119213/wmi-group-policy-filters-that-compare-win32-operatingsystem-buildnumbe), the obvious fix of changing "Version Like" to "version >" won't work, and would end up not applying to Windows 10, but applying to Windows Vista/7/8.

The Microsoft KnowledgeBase gives an example to detect anything Greater than Windows 10 RTM, but I specifically only want to detect Windows 10 Creators and higher. Can anyone assist with a suitable WMI filter?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft don't easily allow that, for the exact reason you found, it's a string, not a number. Please see [WMI Group Policy filters that compare Win32_OperatingSystem BuildNumber don't work as expected on Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3119213/wmi-group-policy-filters-that-compare-win32-operatingsystem-buildnumbe)

A workaround like they wrote is to compare all possible string;

```
Select BuildNumber from Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE  BuildNumber LIKE "%[15063][16299]%"
```

Comment: Hi, Yagmoth. That's similar to my current workaround which is:

`select * from Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE (Version like "10.0.15063%") OR (Version like "10.0.16299%") AND ProductType="1"`

The problem is, every six months, there's going to be a new Windows 10 version number to add to the string, making it more and more unwieldy. is there any WMI wizardry you can use to detect "Creators and above"?

Comment: @Dave A wmi filter for not like old version could be the perfect workaround then. aka Where Not (version like "10.0.96%") and (version like "10.0.10%") and ... That and a wmi filter to detect if its a windows 10 in general.

Comment: Didn't think of using Not. I'll have a go this week, and report back.